# Can not set advice for the methods of the same aspect class

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection, spring-aop

I am trying to learn *SpringAOP* with **AspectJ**, by building a small bank transaction simulation. But I am unable to add advice (@Before, @After, @AfterThrowing) to the methods of the aspect class itself.

This is the model

> **Bank.java**

```
@Component
public class Bank {
    private int balance;
    private int pinCode;
    private int tempPin;

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    @Value("10000")
    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public int getPinCode() {
        return pinCode;
    }

    @Value("6789")
    public void setPinCode(int pinCode) {
        this.pinCode = pinCode;
    }

    public int getTempPin() {
        return tempPin;
    }

    public void setTempPin(int tempPin) {
        this.tempPin = tempPin;
    }

    public void withDraw(int amount) {
        if (amount <= balance) {
            balance -= amount;
            System.out.println("Successful Withdraw");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Insufficient Balance");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the aspect class

> **BankAspect.java**

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class BankAspect {
    private Bank bank;

    public Bank getBank() {
        return bank;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setBank(Bank bank) {
        this.bank = bank;
    }

    @Before("execution(public void dev.ritam.model.Bank.withDraw(..))")
    public void validatePin() {
        if (bank.getPinCode() != bank.getTempPin()) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }

    @AfterThrowing("execution(public void dev.ritam.aspect.BankAspect.validatePin(..))")
    public void logException() {
        System.out.println("Wrong Pin");
    }
}
```

This is the configuration class

> **AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("dev.ritam")
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    Bank bank() {
        return new Bank();
    }

    @Bean
    BankAspect bankAspect() {
        return new BankAspect();
    }
}
```

This is the main method

> **App.java**

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Bank bank = context.getBean(Bank.class);

        try {
            bank.setTempPin(1234);
            bank.withDraw(1000000);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
        }
    }
}
```

Only `validatePin()` `@Before` advice is getting executed. I am suppose to get '*Wrong Pin*' as output, but the `@AfterThrowing` advice is not being recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-at-aspectj) :

> **Advising aspects with other aspects?**
> In Spring AOP, aspects themselves
> cannot be the targets of advice from other aspects. The @Aspect
> annotation on a class marks it as an aspect and, hence, excludes it
> from auto-proxying.

You cannot advice an aspect in Spring AOP and that is the reason for `@AfterThrowing` not executing.

To throw the exception and to log the message , you can advice the same method `Bank.withDraw()` with `@AfterThrowing`. That way, the `validatePin()` advice will get executed before `Bank.withDraw()` and `logException()` advice will get executed if an exception was thrown from validation. This is the second option mentioned in the answer from @dreamcash.

Example code

```
@Before("execution(public void dev.ritam.model.Bank.withDraw(..))")
public void validatePin() {
    if (bank.getPinCode() != bank.getTempPin()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}

@AfterThrowing("execution(public void dev.ritam.model.Bank.withDraw(..))")
public void logException() {
    System.out.println("Wrong Pin");
}
```

This would result in the following sequence of console output

```
Wrong Pin
java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Couple of points to consider.

`Bank` and `BankAspect` are annotated with `@Component` and `@ComponentScan` would register them as beans. Which means beans registered with `@Bean` in AppConfig is not required. Either of the two is required.

The last option mentioned in @dreamcrash's answer is not supported through [Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) : Refer section starting with **Other pointcut types**

**Update**:

This was tricky one , the answer I suggested was based on
Spring Boot Version : 2.2.6.RELEASE
which uses spring libraries from version : 5.2.5.RELEASE

The [code shared](https://github.com/RitamChakraborty/bank_transaction_springaop/tree/r_g_answer) by OP is based on Spring Version : 5.3.1 and the advices are not executing as expected.

The Spring AOP advices in the code shared to work as expected, the spring version should be <= 5.2.6.RELEASE

Please update the the pom.xml entry from

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

For quick reference, following is OP's code that is not working with version `5.3.1`

```
@After("execution(public void dev.ritam.model.Bank.setTempPin(..))")
public void validatePin() {
    if (bank.getPinCode() != bank.getTempPin()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong Pin");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Correct Pin");
    }
}

@AfterThrowing(value = "execution(public void dev.ritam.model.Bank.setTempPin(..))", throwing = "e")
public void logException(Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Not sure if this change in behaviour is documented or not or this is a bug.
Any further information on this will be updated if I find any.

**Info:**

This appears to be a framework issue . More details here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26202

Relevant bits from the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering) ,

> As of **Spring Framework 5.2.7**, advice methods defined in the same
> @Aspect class that need to run at the same join point are assigned
> precedence based on their advice type in the following order, from
> highest to lowest precedence: @Around, @Before, @After,
> @AfterReturning, @AfterThrowing. Note, however, that due to the
> implementation style in Spring’s AspectJAfterAdvice, an @After advice
> method will effectively be invoked after any @AfterReturning or
> @AfterThrowing advice methods in the same aspect.

Comment: I tried the example code you've given. It didn't work out.

Comment: What didn’t work  ? Did you print the error stack from ‘ignore’ object ? The code was tested before the answer was given

Comment: This should work. Because the OP wants to do something both before and after the same method, an alternative would be to just use an `@Around` advice doing both validation and error logging. It is a trade-off between code coherence and separation of concerns, though. This example does not seem to be "real world" anyway. Probably you would have a separate, generic exception logger aspect and put the cause "wrong PIN" into the runtime exception's constructor where it belongs, i.e. logging the exception would also log the correct cause automatically along with the stack trace.

Comment: @R.G I'm not judging you or anything, maybe I lack knowledge in this. I've made a [repo](https://github.com/RitamChakraborty/bank_transaction_springaop) which is little different than the question I had posted. But still having same issue.

I've tried your solution [r_g_answer](https://github.com/RitamChakraborty/bank_transaction_springaop/tree/r_g_answer) branch. Please point out my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: @RitamChakraborty I am sorry if my reply came across as rude and offended you someway. "It didn't work" conveys no useful information and my question was "what didn't work?". I am also here to learn and the person who replied to this question after my comment is my guru here. let me debug your code and see if I could improve the answer . Thank you for the sample code

Answer (score 1):

The method `public void validatePin()` (in the class `BankAspect`) acts as an *advice*; therefore, if you were using `AspectJ` *alone* you could not intercepted it in the way you where doing (*e.g.,* you would need to use the pointcut `adviceexecution`). In the case of `Spring AOP` things are even more strict; `Spring AOP` does not allow aspects to be the targets of *advices*.

To solve your problem you can intercept the same method that is being intercepted by *before* pointcut, namely:

```
@AfterThrowing("execution(public void dev.ritam.model.Bank.withDraw(..))")
public void logException() {
    System.out.println("Wrong Pin");
}
```

since the exception will be thrown within the scope of the method `Bank.withDraw` your `@AfterThrowing` pointcut will be able to catch that exception.

**For AspectJ only**

A straightforward solution, would be to wrap this code:

```
  if (bank.getPinCode() != bank.getTempPin()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
```

into a method, for instance:

```
public void check_pin_code() {
    if (bank.getPinCode() != bank.getTempPin()) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

now intercept that method instead:

```
@AfterThrowing("execution(public void dev.ritam.aspect.BankAspect.check_pin_code(..))")
public void logException() {
    System.out.println("Wrong Pin");
}
```

Another alternative approach, but that one has to be careful using, would be to use `adviceexecution()`

```
@AfterThrowing("within(BankAspect) && adviceexecution()")
public void logException() {
    System.out.println("Wrong Pin");
}
```

This will intercept all the *advice* executions that have happened within the `BankAspect` and that resulted in throwing an Exception.